# Считанный или считаный (о времени - дни, часы, секунды) - информация противоречива, как быть?

Tags: орфография

**[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)**

СЧИТАННЫЙ, -ая, -ое. Очень малый по количеству, числу; единичный. ***Остались считанные часы до отъезда***.

---

> В постановке «Любовь и всякое такое» я знаю, что не могу настроиться
>   целиком на спектакль, поэтому готовлю себя на каждый новый выход, хотя
>   иногда для этого есть лишь считаные секунды, так как пьеса состоит из
>   четырёх не связанных между собою рассказов

.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово считаные в значении 'очень немногие' пишется с одним Н. Написание этого слова приведено в  2000 г. в соответствие общему правилу: в отглагольных прилагательных, образованных от бесприставочных глаголов несовершенного вида, пишется одно Н. Раньше написание считанный приводилось в списке исключений, этим и вызвана фиксация с двумя Н в Большом толковом словаре.

По Лопатину:

Влияние Свода 2000: Отказ от орфографического разграничения причастий и прилагательных (не на -ованный, -еванный), образованных от глаголов несовершенного вида; для тех и других принимаются написания с одним н: жареная на масле картошка и жареная картошка, коротко стриженые волосы и стриженые волосы, гружёные дровами повозки и гружёные повозки. Для образований от глаголов совершенного вида сохраняются единые написания с двумя нн (брошенный, конченный, лишённый, решённый и др.).Глагольный вид определяется наличием/отсутствием приставки: все образования от глаголов несовершенного вида - бесприставочные, в то время как бесприставочные глаголы совершенного вида представляют собой очень немногочисленную группу. Под новое правило естественно подпадают образования деланый (деланое равнодушие), считаный (считаные минуты) и доморощеный, до сих пор писавшиеся с нн, а также конченный (конченный человек), писавшееся с одним н. ) § 64. [https://pravopisanie.academic.ru/16/%C2%A7_058-069.*%D0%94%D0%92%D0%9E%D0%99%D0%9D%D0%AB%D0%95*%D0%A1%D0%9E%D0%93%D0%9B%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%9D%D0%AB%D0%95](https://pravopisanie.academic.ru/16/%C2%A7_058-069._%D0%94%D0%92%D0%9E%D0%99%D0%9D%D0%AB%D0%95_%D0%A1%D0%9E%D0%93%D0%9B%D0%90%D0%A1%D0%9D%D0%AB%D0%95)  Это ссылка на Правила, принятые Академией наук с учётом положений Свода, не отвергнутых комиссией. Сам Свод не принят, многое отвергнуто, но кое-что приняли, правила исправили с учётом мнения Лопатина и его приверженцев. Об этом говорит первый же параграф, ведь Свод предлагал написание парашут. И других непринятых изменений здесь нет, а вот считаные минуты, деланый, зорянку из исключений убрали. Видно, уже назрело. Действуют сейчас и новые, и старые Правила (1956г.) - факультативно.Образование консервативно, ждёт распоряжения Правительства, но его после мнения Л.Путиной, отвергнувшей Свод, не было и, видимо, долго не будет.

Comment: Ужасти, однако, какия: ***жареная на масле картошка и жареная картошка, коротко стриженые волосы и стриженые волосы, гружёные дровами повозки и гружёные повозки...***

Comment: Да, меня тоже напрягает. А ещё напрягает, что в школьных учебниках ничего не изменили. Кто учится по старым учебникам, все исключения так и остались.

Comment: И мне не нравится волюнтаризм с периодическим приведением к единомыслию. Особенно жалко птичку з**о**рянку. Лучше бы ра́новцы упраздняли лишние запятые в сдвоенных препинаниях, которые воспринимаются как символ чиха.

Comment: Сашенька, а что у нас с толкованием-пересказом Ахмадулиной, м?

Comment: Могу только общее впечатление поведать. Видимо, героиня ощущала, что _должна_ в этот сезон что-то написать.  Возможно, уговор с издательством на народную тему. Поэтому не "на юг" по обыкновению поехала, а к тётке в ближнее Подмосковье. Многое её разочаровало: люди бегут из деревни, неверие, языческие предрассудки... Но в других аспектах к народу прониклась, старина её увлекала (порылась в старославянском) и пр. Не знаю, угадал ли суть - может, чего зашифровано в потёмках женской поэтической души...

Comment: О! Щас только прочла этот коммент. Всё мимо, Саша!

Comment: **Людмила**, не могли бы Вы отметить явным образом в ответе, что "Свод 2000" до сих пор остаётся **проектом** и нет уверенности, что эти изменения будут утверждены. К сожалению, в теперешнем виде Ваш ответ может ввести пользователей и участников в заблуждение. Спасибо.

Comment: Не думаю, что кого-то ввела в заблуждение. Я дала ссылку на сайт Словари и энциклопедии на Академике, а не на Свод 2000г. Это Правила, принятые Академией наук с учётом положений Свода, не отвергнутых комиссией. Сам свод не принят, многое отвергнуто, но кое-что приняли, правила исправили с учётом мнения Лопатина и его приверженцев.