# Какой свод правил русского языка действует в настоящее время?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Меня несколько озадачила сложившаяся ситуация с написанием двойных **нн** в причастиях несовершенного вида (речь идёт о "**жаренной на масле** картошке"). Изменения были внесены в свод правил от 2000 г. В [этом ответе](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/436471/183462) приводится выдержка из этого свода.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что это только проект изменений (предлагаемые изменения)? Справочник Лопатина издавался на несколько лет позже и не содержит новых правил. Грамота.ру, насколько я понимаю, тоже ориентируется на старый свод правил. Известно ли что-нибудь о том, когда планируется узаконить новые правила?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проект орфографических правил в 2000 году **не был принят,** поэтому в Правила 2006 года **не вошли самые радикальные изменения**, в том числе вопрос об Н и НН в прилагательных и причастиях. На эту тему есть **интересная статья**, где очень подробно описаны все события, связанные с реформами орфографии. http://www.intelros.ru/readroom/nz/nz_71/6973-istoriya-s-orfografiej-neudavshiesyareformy-russkogo-pravopisaniya-vtoroj-poloviny-xx-veka.html

**Я надеюсь, что "новые правила" не будут узаконены никогда.** В указанной статье говорится **о новом подходе к правописанию**. Во-первых, это вариативность форм,  во-вторых,  принцип орфографического «самоупорядочивания». Главное сейчас  ― это преодоление тоталитарного сознания. **Наша система правописания должна выражать смысл текста, иметь определенную степень свободы, нужную автору**, а этого понимания еще нет в сознании людей. Им кажется, что грамотность ― это только условное оформление по жестким правилам и однозначное соответствие этим правилам.