# Существует ли законодательно утверждённый свод правил русского языка?

Tags: правила, документы

Существует ли нормативный документ, регулирующий правила устной и письменной речи? На что можно сослаться в спорах с нормоконтролем?

Comment: См: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/436791/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, правила речи законодательно не регламентированы. Есть общепризнанные учебники, словари. Суд обычно приглашает экспертов-лингвистов. Можно сослаться на прецедентые решения судов.

Это нормоконтроль должен сослаться на нарушение каких-то прописанных в законе или инструкции норм.