# Официально утвержденные правила

Tags: семантика

И еще на тему "официальных" правил.

Раз за разом проскакивают упоминания о неких "официально утвержденных правилах языка". Ну или орфографии.

Обсуждалось уже не раз, вот тут например.
[Существует ли законодательно утверждённый свод правил русского языка?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/446982)
Естественно, что правила языка никто утвердить не может, ибо язык никому не подчиняется. В отношении орфографических, скажем, правил - тут да, можно о чем-то спорить, но все-таки слово "утверждать" к ним вполне применимо.

Но меня интересует в данном случае сам термин "официальный". Верно ли толкование "официально утвержденный"*) в отношении, скажем, сводом правил-56, утверждаемого максимум на уровне АН?!

(+) Там, правда есть еще утверждение министерствами образования (СССР и РСФСР), но подобные функции минобра подобные "утверждения" в Конституции явно не были прописаны. То есть в данном вопросе Минобры выступали как совещательный орган.

Ну в общем нестыковка. Или "официально" надо убрать - или слово "нормы" заменить на что-то менее обязывающее.

*) что "по умолчанию" подразумевает утверждение на государственном уровне, то есть органом, полномочия которого на такое утверждение прописаны либо в Конституции, либо в законах прямого действия

Comment: "но все-таки слово "утверждать" к ним вполне применимо" — Когда мы спорили на эту тему, имел в виду исключительно утверждение орфографических норм орфографической комиссией (на то у неё и такое название). И в новой редакции украинского правописания тоже изменены только орфографические правила.

Comment: Я ни о чем с вами никогда не спорил. Спор в моем понимании предполагает наличие какой-то позиции, предмета спора. Не помню, чтобы вы её хоть раз сформулировали. Это раз. Второе. Вопрос задан так как он8 задан. Что было раньше - никого по большому счету уже не интересует.

Comment: Да спорили - в отношении слова "юный" уж точно. Ладно, проехали. Получается, что орфографию могут утверждать - спорные случаи, подходя к вопросу разумно. Кроме Украины, где вместо "i" в начале слов разрешили писать "и".

Comment: Не могу принять вашу трактовку событий. Может, вы и спорили, но я точно - нет. И хватит об этом. Никому это не интересно.

Comment: Если вы не спорили, то я тоже нет. Назовём это стремлением что-то доказать.

Comment: Вы можете называть как угодно, но, пожалуйста, не используйте множественного числа. Я категорический против таких названий.

Comment: "В пререкания с вами вступать более не намерен." — Из словаря Кузнецова: *пререкаться — спорить, препираться*. Как-то так...